# Is this method for proving a result about three matrices valid?

Tags: matrices, vectors, matrix-equations

Let $A,B,C \in M_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ be fixed and let $x,y,z \in M_{3 \times 1}(\mathbb{R})$ be any three column vectors. Consider the matrix equation given by:

$Ax + By + Cz = 0_{3 \times 1}$

Suppose that I would like to prove some result involving $A$, $B$, and $C$ given the above equation. Would it be enough to prove the result separately in the following cases?

Case 1: $Ax=0_{3 \times 1}$, $By=0_{3 \times 1}$, and $Cz=0_{3 \times 1}$.

Case 2: $By+Cz=0_{3 \times 1}$.

Case 3: $Ax+Cz=0_{3 \times 1}$.

Case 4: $Ax+By=0_{3 \times 1}$.

Case 5: $By+Cz\neq0_{3 \times 1}$.

Case 6: $Ax+Cz\neq0_{3 \times 1}$.

Case 7: $Ax+By\neq0_{3 \times 1}$.

Comment: It looks to me like case 1 is equivalent to cases 2-4, given your equation.

Comment: Case 2 and case 5 are suffice.

Comment: @SantanaAfton Really? I would think that, in Case 2 for instance, $By$ and $Cz$ are allowed to be nonzero so long as they are additive inverses for each other.

Comment: @Yanko Why should that be the case?

Comment: Because they exclude each other and one of them is always true.

Comment: @David Oops, I copy-pasted my typo nine times.

Comment: @J_Psi I might not understand the question, but as I understand a matrix can either be zero or not and so cases 2,5 are suffice.

Comment: @Yanko I see now, Yanko. Thank you for that.

Comment: If one of the matrices is invertible, the solution is easy. If, e.g., $A$ is invertible, then the solution space is $\{(-A^{-1}(By+Cz),y,z) : y,z\in\Bbb R^3\}$.